# Backup and recover database with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-backups

I would like to have the possibility to backup and recover the database through Hibernate.

the flow is:

1) Get all entities from each table to HashMap and whole map serialize to file.

2) Clear all entities from Database.

3) Deserialize the file and persist all entities back to the database.

In step 3, I am facing the:

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [*.*.entities.User#1]
```

This happens with this piece of code:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
session.getTransaction().commit(); // <- here
```

All of my entities extends BasicEntity, which has only this ID definition:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

What am I doing wrong? I think, that I cant save entity (recover from file), which has some ID, but I need to do it and save the current ID (to keep links between entities), but the hibernate wont let me do this.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827576/what-does-mean-hibernates-unsaved-value-mapping-was-incorrect). Since it is not a transaction issue it has to do with the `or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect` part. I'd rather rely on database mechanisms for backup and recovery, though.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like another thread updated in db before the current commit.
try one of the below options

```
//check if it's in the cache, if it's then refresh and then saveorupdate
if (session.contains(entity) session.refresh(entity);
saveOrUpdate(entity);

//Load the object from the database and then update
dbEntity= session.load(classname.class, 2);
saveOrUpdate(dbEntity);
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem. Everything is happening in one thread. The entities no longer exists in database. I have restore them from file as java instances with ids which they have before delete and now I need to save them back again.